# Trying to run a Java program from the command prompt

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to run my program via command prompt like this

```
java Analis.arno txts.txt 550
```

Here is my code:

```
static Painter p;
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
    p = new Painter(args[0]);
    p.paintModuleStatisticbyAge(null, Integer.parseInt(args[1]), 10, 80);   
}
```

When I run it from "Run config" it works, but from the command prompt, I get:

```
FileNOtFoundException
```

Comment: So, are you sure the file `txts.txt` is in the right directory?

Comment: I pass it as a string argument to my Painter(), it works when i run it from eclips Run Config like `txts.txt 550`

Comment: By passing `txts.txt` like that from the command line, you imply that you are placing both your jar and your text file at the same directory level.

Comment: yes @Tavo, my text is there

Comment: Can you post the exception here, just to make sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you run it from your Run Config in Eclipse, the relative path starts in your project folder, but with the jar file your path starts in the directory where the jar file lives.

Let's assume this structure:

[image: Project structure]

When you run from Eclipse, your base directory will be tmp. But if you go to the command line to `tmp\out` and run `java Analis.arno txts.txt 550`, your base directory will be `tmp\out` and not `tmp`.

Comment: `C:\Users\arno\workspace\Arno\src>java Analis.arno txts.txt 550
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: txts.txt (The system c
annot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at Analis.GetStatisticFromFile.getModuleStatisticsByArg(GetStatisticFrom
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the `txts.txt` file in the same directory as the `.class` file

```
ProjectRoot
       bin
          Analis
               txts.txt
               arno.class
       src
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileNotFound exception means that the file you are passing as arg[0] ,"txts.txt" is not available.

ideally the file should be present in the directory you are launching the program from, or you should pass in full path of the file.

```
ROOT
  src
   Analis
     arno.java       
  bin 
   txts.txt
   Analis
     arno.class
```

You should launch from Root/bin passing `java Analis.arno txts.txt`

Comment: the program doesn't work only from cmd, I read the file if I put `Painter("txts.txt")`

Comment: In that case you can try printing the value of arg[0] on screen to see what value is recieved by program

Comment: I have tried. it prints the same, I have even tried to count chars in case if there is tabulation

Comment: can you share the location you are launching the program from , also try passing the absolute file name to see if thats the issue . share the directory structure

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the path for the file explicitly if both the program and the text file are not in the same directory.

Try:

`java Analis.arno path/to/txts.txt 550`